# Non-orthogonal matrix representation of dihedral groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, dihedral-groups

I found this table on [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_dihedral_groups):

[image]

$a$ is the first element of a dihedral group $D_n$, i.e. the rotation by an angle $2\pi/n$.

Few questions on that:

1) **Non real, non orthogonal** representation matrices.

Let's take a vector, say $\left ( \begin{array} & 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right )$.

- For a real, orthonogal matrix, we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$:
  $\left ( \begin{array} & \cos(2\pi k/n) & -\sin(2\pi k/n) \\ \sin(2\pi k/n) & \cos(2\pi k/n) \end{array} \right ) \cdot \left ( \begin{array} & 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right ) = \left ( \begin{array} & \cos(2\pi k/n) \\ \sin(2\pi k/n) \end{array} \right ), $ which is fine ✅.
- For a complex unitary matrix, we are in $\mathbb{C}^2$: 
  $\left ( \begin{array} & e^{2\pi ik/n} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{2\pi ik/n} \end{array} \right ) \cdot \left ( \begin{array} & 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right ) = \left ( \begin{array} & e^{2\pi ik/n} \\ 0 \end{array} \right ), $ so in $\mathbb{C}$ I get $\cos(2\pi k/n) + i\sin(2\pi k/n)$ which is the same as above so it's fine ✅.

-

The 4th column is the issue.

- What is $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/n))$ and **what does it mean**?
- If I take a vecor $\left ( \begin{array} & 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right )$ (in what space??), and use the matrix from the table:
  $\left ( \begin{array} & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 2\cos{2\pi k/n} \end{array} \right ) \cdot \left ( \begin{array} & 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right ) = \left ( \begin{array} & 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right )$, **what does this mean** ?

-

2) Also, how does the **minimal polynomial help/fit in findig the representation**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you know that in this representation, a generator of the rotations part of the group is meant to act by rotating the plane by the angle $2 \pi k /n$. Writing that transformation down as a matrix with real coefficients requires a choice of basis of the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If the standard basis $e_1, e_2$ is chosen, i.e., a unit vector along the $x$-axis and a unit vector along the $y$-axis, then we get the "real orthogonal" column of that table, which is the expected rotation matrix.

To get the other column, draw a regular unit $n$-gon in the plane, centred at the origin. Each vertex of the $n$-gon is a unit vector: choose two adjacent ones and call those $v_1$, $v_2$. Now, how is a rotation through $2 \pi / n$ written in this basis? Write $R$ for the rotation: we must have $R v_1 = v_2$ by our choice of basis. Some coordinate geometry should then tell you that, in terms of $v_1$ and $v_2$, $R v_2 = -v_1 + 2 \cos(2 \pi / n) v_2$. So in the basis $(v_1, v_2)$, the matrix of $R$ is
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & - 1 \\ 1 & 2 \cos(2 \pi / n) \end{pmatrix}$$
and taking this matrix to the power $k$ will give a rotation by $2 \pi k / n$.

So there is no difference in the representations: they are just the same representation written down using different bases. This is what it means to be isomorphic as representations. The characteristic polynomial of a matrix is invariant under change of basis, which could be why the table lists it as well.

Finally, $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is notation which means the [field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension#Examples) of $\mathbb{Q}$ by the element $a$, where $a$ could be real or complex. Here the table is just noting what $\mathbb{Q}$ needs to be extended by to make the representation work, which here is just cosine of a particular angle. (Notably, we do not need the full power of the complex numbers).

---

*Later addition*: How can we derive the matrix $R$? Let
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(2 \pi / n) & -\sin(2 \pi / n) \\ \sin(2 \pi / n) & \cos(2 \pi / n) \end{pmatrix}$$
be the rotation matrix. We essentially want to find a basis in which $M$ will only have rational numbers and $\cos(2 \pi / n)$. Let $v_1$ be any nonzero vector in the plane, and let $v_2 = Mv_1$ be the rotation applied to $v_1$. Then we want to compute $Mv_2 = M^2 v_1$ in the $(v_1, v_2)$ basis. $M$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial $x^2 - 2 \cos(2 \pi / n) x + 1 = 0$, and so we have
$$M^2 v_1 - 2 \cos(2 \pi / n) Mv_1 + v_1 = 0$$
which we rearrange to see
$$Mv_2 = -v_1 + 2 \cos(2 \pi / n) v_2$$
which gives the second column of the matrix $R$.

Comment: Great, thanks! But $\mathbb{Q}$ already has any of the $\cos(2\pi/n)$... so why do we need to extend the field?

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ often does not have the $\cos(2 \pi / n)$. For example, $\cos(2 \pi / 8) = 1/\sqrt{2}$, which is irrational.

Comment: Oh wait sorry I though $\mathbb{Q}$ were the irrationals! Thanks. What is the symbol for transcendental numbers then?

Comment: I'm not sure if they have a good symbol. You could go with $\mathbb{C} \setminus \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, but then you get "complex transcendental" numbers too. Perhaps just use the word :P

Comment: what does the overline on the Q do?

Comment: It means the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, where you adjoint every root of every polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Does it mean the complement of Q?

Comment: What does 'adjoint' mean in this case?

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to read "adjoin". The algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ of the rationals contains every number which is a root of a polynomial with rational coefficients. For example, the existence of the polynomials $x^2 + 1$ and $x^2 - 2$ means that the numbers $i$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ are in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. If you are interested in topics like this, you might like to read about field extensions, and Galois theory.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up after so long. But I’m still baffled by how you for the $Rv_2$ expression. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @SuperCiocia I've updated my answer with a different way of deriving the action of a rotation on the $(v_1, v_2)$ basis. Of course, you could also just conjugate the rotation matrix by the change-of-basis matrix.

Comment: I understand the characteristic polynomial comes from the eignevalue condition, where $x$ being the eigenvalues. But why do you set $x = Mv_1$?

Comment: It’s not setting $x = Mv_1$, since that doesn’t make sense. It’s setting $x=M$, then applying the resulting equation to $v_1$. And like I said, just try writing out a change of basis matrix and conjugating $M$, it will give the same answer.

Comment: I understand, thanks very much!